# How to construct unique_ptr<T[],D>(specialization for arrays)?

Tags: c++, unique-ptr

```
template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u ) noexcept;(6)
```

I find that unique_ptr<T[],D> has many constructors.But I don't know how to create a unique_ptr<T[],D> with function**(6)**.Could you tell me how to call it?Thanks.

Reference:https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/unique_ptr

Comment: What  have you tried? Do you know what the second template parameter is supposed to be?

Comment: what's the problem, do you have  anippet where it fails? it's a move constructor and example of call to it is right in the link you provided

Answer (score 1):

You could use `make_unique` as shown below:

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(2);
```

Or

If you want to pass a custom deleter then one way would be to use `std::function` as shown below:

```
auto ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(2);

//here we use lambda as a deleter  
std::unique_ptr<int[], std::function<void(int[])>> PTR(new int[2](), [](int*p)->void
{
    std::cout<<"lambda called"<<std::endl;
    delete[]p ;
});
std::unique_ptr<int[], std::function<void(int[])>> P2(std::move(PTR));

//or more readable
//auto P2 = std::move(PTR);
```

[Working demo](https://onlinegdb.com/VzuoxsKvR).

---

Using a separate function instead of `lambda` is also possible and trivial as shown below:

```
//use a free function as deleter 
void func(int p[])
{
    std::cout<<"func called"<<std::endl;
    delete[]p ;
}
int main()
{
    auto ptr = std::make_unique<int[]>(2);
    
    std::unique_ptr<int[], std::function<void(int[])>> PTR(new int[2](), func);
     std::unique_ptr<int[], std::function<void(int[])>> up6b(std::move(PTR));

//or more readable 
//auto up6b = std::move(PTR);
}
```

[Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/R_33jtrMx)

Comment: Isn't your provided code an example of constructor 3/4 according to the cppreference?

Comment: @kuro What is constructor 3/4? Can you share a link to what is constructor 3/4.

Comment: check the link that OP provided. OP is asking for the 6th variant of the constructor. I think it is a move constructor

Comment: Can even do `auto up6b = std::move(PTR);.` Following `std::cout << PTR << typeid(PTR).name() << "\n";
    auto up6b = std::move(PTR);
    std::cout << up6b << " " << typeid(up6b).name() << "\n";` is a proof

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, i have added the use of `auto` as per your suggestion as comment in my answer. TBH personally in my projects i prefer to be as explicit as possible and so when working on a pet project i typically use the explicit form instead of using `auto`. This makes it easier for me to understand code. But that is a personal preference.

Comment: @AnoopRana mmm.. yes, when not working with generic (template, generic lambda) code that helps to search for usage of type, too. Though type changing through code during refactor creates problems , unless we introduce alias names for all explicit types.

Answer (score 1):

`unique_ptr` cannot be copied, so doesn't have a copy constructor. Constructors 5 and 6 are move constructors, which remove pointer ownership from original object and give it to new one.

```
unique_ptr( unique_ptr&& u ) noexcept;  // (5)  (constexpr since C++23)

template< class U, class E >
unique_ptr( unique_ptr<U, E>&& u ) noexcept;    // (6)  (constexpr since C++23)
```

In example the `up6b` and `up6d` are using the call to that function.

After the call, the smart pointers `up6a` and `up6c` do not point at object they were pointing before.

```
std::cout << "Example constructor(6)...\n";
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo, D> up6a(new Foo, d); // D is copied
    std::unique_ptr<Foo, D> up6b(std::move(up6a)); // D is moved

    std::unique_ptr<Foo, D&> up6c(new Foo, d); // D is a reference
    std::unique_ptr<Foo, D> up6d(std::move(up6c)); // D is copied
}
```

Most common occurrence of move constructor invocation before C++17 was the initialization with `make_unique`. You easily can do this:

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> a(new int[10]);
std::unique_ptr<int[]> b(std::move(a));
```

But if you're trying to use make_unique ,  the latter needs invocation of specialization for an array allocation.

```
std::unique_ptr<int[]> b = std::make_unique<int[]>(10);
```

Note, that this isn't necessary invoke move constructor mentioned above.

Comment: OP asked for `T[]` form but you've provided non-array form.

Comment: @AnoopRana it doesn't have array form. In C++ unlike in C, arrays and structs are types not blocks. So `Foo = T[]` and in this case `unique_ptr` ctor is type agnostic (its destructor isn't). Op doesn't provide example where it fails and possible syntax edge cases  they can run into is hard to predict. Are they failing at constructing original?

Comment: OP could've provided an example of the current code that they have. That would have been more clear because it would clarify whether OP is struggling in constructing the original or just in transferring ownership.

Comment: @AnoopRana well, that constructor usable only for transferring in this case.

Comment: Yes agreed. So does this mean in my shown example i can't write/add `std::unique_ptr<int[], std::function<void(int[])>> P2(std::move(PTR));` after constructing `PTR`? I am not sure. Will that be UB or well-formed.

Comment: But `PTR` is a unique_ptr` not a raw pointer. And i am doing `std::move(PTR)`.

Comment: @Wxz you also would need `new Foo[size]`, right? Most of time you wouldn't get problems from using `delete[]` on something made by `new` instead of `new[]`, but it's implementation-defined. At least `new Foo[1]`

Comment: @AnoopRana yes, agreed. I withdraw my remark, didn't look straight at it. You can , of course. You even can use `auto` to avoid that boilerplate.

Comment: I replace FOO with FOO[],it works.I thought the first parameter should be changed to resolve polymorphism or implicit conversion. Changing the first parameter has not been able to compile.But it seems that this function is designed to accommodate different deleters.

Comment: @Wxz Yes, you can use custom deleter as shown in my example.

Comment: @Wxz yes, because pointer's deleter is part of smart pointer's type.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Good that we are on the same page.

Comment: If it would be easily possible to use `delete[]` on memory allocated with `new`, then `delete[]` could be always used, and `delete` would be implemented as `delete[]`. But in practice they typically are NOT. Arrays often get additional internal data in front of the first element.

Comment: @Sebastian yeah, my point.  Some _ancient_ codebases got away with it, which suddenly causes bugs from porting "previously well-formed and  used for years software", because  in some older implementations  `new type[1]` was implemented same as  `new type` for simplicity of implementation,